# Mysql SUM and GROUP BY from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 database tables as follows:

## projects:

`id`

`project_name`

`project_location`

`status`

## project_expenses

`id`

`project_id`

`expense_category`

`expense_subcategory`

`amount`

`userid`

`date`

`payment_status`

`project_status`

## project_income

`id`

`project_id`

`project_income`

`date`

`userid`

`project_status`

projects.id, project_expenses.project_id and project_income.project_id are related.

I need to create a query displaying **Project_ID,Project_Name,SUM of Project_Income,SUM of Project_expenses**

I tried the following query but not getting correct result.

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.project_name AS project_name, SUM(i.project_income) AS income, SUM(e.amount) AS expenses
FROM project_income i, project_expenses e, projects p
WHERE i.project_id = p.id AND e.project_id = p.id AND p.status = 'Active'
GROUP BY id
```

I have currently 2 rows in project_income and 4 rows in project_expenses. The result is project_income displays double the values. Something is wrong with my JOIN.

Being a newbie I am unable to understand what i am doing wrong?? Requesting help...

Comment: Use sub queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sub-selects in the query result columns. No need for `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.project_name
     , ( SELECT SUM(i.project_income)
           FROM project_income i
          WHERE i.project_id = p.id
       ) AS income
     , ( SELECT SUM(e.amount)
           FROM project_expenses e
          WHERE e.project_id = p.id
       ) AS expenses
  FROM projects p
 WHERE p.status = 'Active'
```

---

The problem with the query in the question is best explained with an example.

You say there are 2 rows in `project_income` and 4 rows in `project_expenses`. Let say the 2 incomes are 1000 and 1500, and the 4 expenses are 615, 750, 840, and 900.

Since there are no restrictions between them, that means you'll get the cross join, i.e. 8 records:

```
income  expense
1000    615
1000    750
1000    840
1000    900
1500    615
1500    750
1500    840
1500    900
```

Now, when you sum `income` you get 4 times the value you want, and when you sum expense you get 2 times the value you want.